# Setting WebViewClient to WebView doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I am writing an app that should authorize with Twitter. I load a WebView Link to my app's server, which redirects me to the Twitter authorization page. Before this, the user is logged in on my app server with DefaultHttpClient.

If I just write `_webView.loadUrl(link);` then everything works correctly, but if I add  `_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});` before loading link - it redirects me to authorization on my app's server.

What should I do to remove this redirection?